# C# Accessing Method from Controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a folder called 'classes' and in this folder I have a class called ConverImages.cs

In this file is the following code:

```
namespace VehicleAudits2_v1.classes
{
    public class ConvertImage
    {
        public Image base64ToImage(string base64String)
        {
            // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
            imageBytes.Length);

           // Convert byte[] to Image
           ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
           Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
           return image;

      }
   }
}
```

How would I call this from a controller?   If this code was I the controller I would just call it directly like so:

```
base64ToImage(ImageString);
```

but I can't figure out how to call from external file and searching on the internet has not come up with anything

Comment: you'd probably be well served to pick up a book on c# and object oriented programming in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include **namespace** in your controller class and call the method this way:

```
using VehicleAudits2_v1.classes;

public class SomeController : Controller
{

  public ActionResult SomeAction()
  {
    ConvertImage convert = new ConvertImage();
    convert.base64ToImage("SomeValue");
    return View();

  }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Make your method `static`:

```
public static Image base64ToImage(string base64String)
```

Then refer to it in your controller using `<class_name>.<method_name>` :

```
ConvertImage.base64ToImage(ImageString);
```

Comment: I don't understand why the hell you people(you and @Rik) are suggesting to make the method static?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Please educate me, and explain why you think `static` is a bad idea? AFAIK, the method `base64ToImage` takes a random input to process and generate an output, and does not depend on any of its parent class's members, so is a perfect candidate for a static method (Helper class design pattern).

Comment: If you ask the same question to google, you'll get lot of answers. My two cents are [here](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/01/29/static-methods-will-shock-you/) and [Helper classes also should be avoided](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/04/12/should-i-leave-that-helper-class/).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Thanks. We're all here to help and learn a little in the process, so a little courtesy will go a long way. [Be nice!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/180532); a nice explanation would've been so much better than `why the hell`.

Comment: I usually try to be nice, but two answers suggesting *pit of despair* annoyed me. :|

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: In every possible situation, [be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/180532). This isn't your personal rant blog.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63481/discussion-between-snag-and-sriram-sakthivel).